# Make a list of data frames out of pandas query?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am curious as to how I can make a list of data frames out of pandas query.

```
df = pd.read_csv('my_data.csv')

listOfDataframes = [df.query('foo == i')['bar'].value_counts() for i in range(1,4,1)]
```

This gives me an error that i is not defined. I would imagine that I need to use some sort of string formatting for this, but I am not sure how to incorporate it. Also I feel like there is a better way to do things, but I am not familiar enough with pandas data frames to figure it out. Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: `f'foo == {i}'`  With the current code `'foo == i'` the list-comprehension doesn't know to update `'i'`. I'm voting to close this question as not reproducible / caused by a typo.